# Calculate totals within custom SQL query (Tableau)

Tags: if-statement, tableau-api, visualization

I have a dataset where I wish to reflect the totals from a **custom SQL query** I performed in Tableau. Here is some sample data:

**1. I first performed a custom query that was a join, unpivot and placed my data into groups**

```
Size Tb   Val       type           Group      Sum_AVG    SKU       Last_Refreshed

270      90.5      Free_Space_TB  Group2     90.5       Excel     9/1/2020
270      179.5     Used           Group2     179.5      Excel     9/1/2020
814      701       Free_Space_TB  Group1     701        Gris      8/1/2020
814      112       Used           Group1     112        Gris      8/1/2020
```

**2. Then I aggregated the data by taking the sum of one group and the average of the other group (and final summed these groups values)**

The data is being aggregated like this: (SUM_AVG)

```
zn(sum(if [Group]= 'Group1' then [Val] end))
+
zn(avg(if [Group] = 'Group2' then [Val] end))
```

The view looks like this

[image]

Here is the custom query output
[image]

Here is my view

The avail and used appear when I hover over, but how would I include the total?
[image]

[image]

This is the calculation I am using (thanks to help from a SO member):

```
{SUM({Fixed [type]: ZN(sum(if [Group]= 'Group1' then [Val] end))})
+
sum({Fixed [type]: zn(avg(if [Group] = 'Group2' then [Val] end))})}
```

I am doing something wrong, because it is totaling up across all the column(s), (I have more columns in the full dataset) when I just want the total for each column.

**(Used was created from using a custom query)**

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, this you can do without changing the underlying view.  `WINDOW_SUM` is a table calculation and is always dependent on view/context generated.  Therefore, I always prefer LOD calculations which do not depend on context.

I think you should proceed like this.  As always I have changed the sample data to include sufficient details

**Data used**

```
| Id | Avail | group  | used | Date       |
|----|-------|--------|------|------------|
| A  | 5     | Group1 | 5    | 20-01-2020 |
| A  | 20    | Group1 | 20   | 20-01-2020 |
| B  | 10    | Group2 | 10   | 20-01-2020 |
| B  | 5     | Group2 | 5    | 20-01-2020 |
| B  | 5     | Group2 | 5    | 20-01-2020 |
| A  | 10    | Group1 | 10   | 20-01-2020 |
| A  | 10    | Group1 | 10   | 20-01-2020 |
| B  | 5     | Group2 | 5    | 20-01-2020 |
| B  | 5     | Group2 | 5    | 20-01-2020 |
| A  | 5     | Group1 | 5    | 20-02-2019 |
| A  | 20    | Group1 | 20   | 20-02-2019 |
| B  | 10    | Group2 | 10   | 20-02-2019 |
| B  | 5     | Group2 | 5    | 20-02-2019 |
| B  | 5     | Group2 | 5    | 20-02-2019 |
| A  | 10    | Group1 | 10   | 20-02-2019 |
| A  | 10    | Group1 | 10   | 20-02-2019 |
| B  | 5     | Group2 | 5    | 20-02-2019 |
| B  | 5     | Group2 | 5    | 20-02-2019 |
```

**Step-1** Pivot generated in tableau as earlier.

**Step-2** Calculated field `sum-avg` also generated as discussed.

**step-3** View generated

[image]

**Step-4** Add another field `total`

```
{FIXED [Date], [Group]: sum(
{FIXED [Date], [Group], [type]: zn(sum(if [Group]= 'Group1' then [val] end))}
+
{Fixed [Date], [Group], [type]: zn(avg(if [Group] = 'Group2' then [val] end))}
)}
```

**Step-5** Add this field to **details** on **marks card**.  See the GIF here

[image]

the code used in tooltip is mentioned below.  Obviously, you can tweak it as per taste.

```
Under the <Group> ,  <AGG(Sum_Avg)> was <type> out of total <SUM(Total)> SKU on     <YEAR(Date)>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This solution works:**

1.Create a calculated field:

```
WINDOW_SUM([SUM_AVG])
```

2.Drag newly computed field to the view

3.Right click ‘Edit Table Calculation’

4.Specify and compute using [Last_Refreshed] and [type]

This will allow you to **compute across cells**, giving you your desired result

Comment: So Lynnette, is the problem solved? Please give me a few hours, I'll try to give alternate solution.

Comment: Hi @AnilGoyal what I have presented  works. Ok that will be ok